# Need to order by properties in the reference property, any good solution?

Tags: google-app-engine, join, gql

Say I have 2 kind:

```
class Account(db.Model):
  name = db.StringProperty()

  create_time = db.DataTimeProperty()
  last_login = db.DateTimeProperty()
  last_update = db.DataTimeProperty()


class Relationship(db.Model)
  owner = db.ReferenceProperty(Account)
  target = db.ReferenceProperty(Account)
  type = db.IntegerProperty()
```

I want to get the equivalence of following query:

```
SELECT target 
FROM Relationship
WHERE owner = :key AND type = :type
ORDERBY target.last_login DESC
```

How to do that?

reference: http://www.mail-archive.com/google-appengine@googlegroups.com/msg15878.html

Comment: Robert, it is 'Type' in English not 'kind'

Comment: 'kind' is a term used in App Engine's datastore.

Comment: Oh, I see. Made a fool of myself. :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no equivalent for that query in datastore. Some points:

1. You can't select a single property. `SELECT` is always `SELECT *` (you select a whole entity).
2. You can't do joins. You need to denormalize your models to fit the queries you will perform, or perform multiple queries.

So to achieve your goal, you need to have `last_login` stored in `Relationship`, or have a 3rd model to serve as index for that specific query.

Comment: It's not ideal to store last_login in Relationship, since this will require to update a lot of rows, the cost if simply too high.

Comment: Robert: The datastore can't do joins like a relational database, so your only options are to include the field you want to sort on in the Kind you're querying or to do the sorting in memory.