# How to do something like a SQL JOIN with appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, python-2.7

I need something exactly like a SQL JOIN which cannot be done with appengine so I'm looking for a workaround. This is the query is want sorted by person.lastname

```
downline = User.query(User.sponsor == distributor.key).fetch()
for person in downline
    orders = model.Order.all().filter('distributor_id =' , person.key.id()).filter('created >' , startdate).filter('status =', 'PAID').fetch(999999)
```

The query fetches the orders places by a person and basically I've got 2 kinds of entities, persons and orders. How should I go about to mimic that I join the persons (User) entity and sort the list by person's lastname? This is a very easy thing to do in SQL and I couldn't find a way to do it in appengine.

Can you tell me how I could add the person names in memory? The function doesn't have to have very good performance since it is a reporting function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need to order by properties in the reference property, any good solution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333002/need-to-order-by-properties-in-the-reference-property-any-good-solution)

Comment: The answer to this question is in the answer to my previous question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929943/modelling-in-google-datastore-use-lists-or-separate-entities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect your Person and Order models by parenting - a Person is the parent object of an Order. With that, it becomes simple to iterate over the Person set in order and select its orders.

Another way is to use a ListPoperty if you are using the current API or repeated properties if you are using NDB to link your Order's to your Person's.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use IDs to link models.  That is the SQL approach; you need to adopt a noSQL approach.

Instead of implicitly linking an `Order` with a `User` with a shared ID, simply reference the `User` in the `Order`.

```
class User(db.Model):
    # ...

class Order(db.Model):
    distributor = db.ReferenceProperty(User)
    # ...

# e.g.,
order = Order()
order.distributor = User()
```

Then grab your users, sorting them by `order()`, and then grabbing all associated `Order`s using `filter()` against the appropriate `User`.

```
distributors = User.all().filter('sponser = ', sponser).order('lastname').fetch(i)
for distributor in distributors:
    orders = Order.all().filter('distributor', distributor).fetch(j)
    # ...
```

Comment: That's a good answer but I had to link the entities with IDs since the User object is an NDB expando model. I'll try to find other ways but this was the only way I could get a somewhat working solution.

Answer (score -1):

If you really don't care about performance and this is for one-off reporting type work you might want to look at using the remote-api.